# Streaming API not working?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, stellar-laboratory

I'm trying to enable streaming via the REST API but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
curl -H "Accept: text/event-stream" "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/payments"
```

This curl statement only returns a list of payments but it doesn't stream any.

Even the stellar tools explorer isn't working when put in stream mode...

https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#explorer?resource=operations&endpoint=all&values=eyJzdHJlYW1pbmciOnRydWUsIm9yZGVyIjoiZGVzYyIsImxpbWl0IjoiMTAwIn0%3D&network=public

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream is closed with `200 OK` status after sending a specific number of events (as far as I remember: 10 events). Curl does not implement Server-Sent Events specification correctly. According to SSE spec client should reconnect to the stream if connection was closed.

Another issue with your request is that you did not pass `cursor` parameter. In such case Horizon will stream events from the oldest so the first payments that were submitted to the network a few years ago. Add `cursor=now` to stream recent payments.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming mode is working just fine. Try [code samples](https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-sdk/reference/examples.html#streaming-payment-events) from official docs.

However, `curl` doesn't work as expected for some reason. I checked the specification, `curl` has support of Server Sent Events (format used by Horizon API). So it seems to me that Horizon server does not fully support the protocol. Try to use one of Stellar SDKs instead.

Comment: Using one of the Stellar SDKs is not viable as there is none for the language I'm using. 

Every attempt to consume SSE sent by Horizon fails, but but the same code is able to consume SSE's sent by other sources just fine, so i'm a bit confused...